# Onclick isn't being registered, keep telling me it's undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to have a menu slide in whenever the 'menu' icon is clicked. Now I can't see where I went wrong. I'm getting the 'menu is not defined' error in the console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Menu rechts</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="web_wrapper">
        <header>
            <main style="width: 100%;">
                <button class="material-icons" id="menu_toggle" onclick="menu()">menu</button>
            </main>
        </header>
    </section>
    <section class="menu_show">
        <nav style="right: -20%;">
            <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
            </ul>
        <nav>
    </section>
<script src"toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The used javascript

```
function menu()
{
  var menu = document.querySelector("nav");
  var main = document.querySelector("main");

  if(menu.style.right != '-20%')
  {
      menu.style.right='-20%';
      main.style.width='100%';
  }
  else
  {
      menu.style.right='0%';
      main.style.width='80%';
  }
}
```

The css 
After getting comments it seems it might be a css issue. Because of this reason i'm also posting the css.

```
* {
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0; }

body {
  width: 100%;
  color: #212121; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

li {
  list-style-type: none; }

.web_wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; }

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; }
  header main {
    height: 75px; }
    header main button#menu_toggle.material-icons {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
      left: 1000px;
      background: transparent;
      transition: transform 0.3s, color 0.3s;
      font-size: 24pt !important; }
    header main button.active {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
      color: #536DFE; }

.menu_show {
  height: 100vh;
  float: right;
  background: #607D8B; }
  .menu_show nav {
    width: 20%; }
    .menu_show nav ul {
      width: 100%; }
      .menu_show nav ul li {
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center; }
```

Comment: If you've jQuery loaded, why not use jQuery functions?

Comment: I had a jQuery markup earlier, but that failed me aswell sadly. I feel more comfortable with javascript so I went back on that trying to fix the issue

Comment: try to put function code in <head> section

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt Your code works fine http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/enzpr2sj/, is the complete code added in question?

Comment: Thanks for responding Uday. Sadly this isn't working either. The error does disappear. But the event still isn't being triggered on click.

Comment: @UdayHiwarale is right. look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ppckwgwc/1/  if you change tha way you want to wrap your javascript (onload or ondocument) your function becomes "undefined"

Comment: @Tushar I have the entire code running on my localhost. The error is gone after putting the code into the head part of my code. But i'm still not getting the script to actually do it's work

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio He was right indeed, and the error is gone. Yet, the script is still not running / doing what i'm trying to make it do.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio, UdayHiwarale It doesn't matter in this case where the script is included, because it only contains a global function that'll be called when element is clicked.

Comment: `menu()` method needs to be defined on global scope. I guess your posted code is missing relevant context

Comment: And FINALLY, I've got the answer: Add `position: relative;` on the `nav`. Check http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/enzpr2sj/1/. `right` will not work until element is positioned.

Comment: From your comment to @sajanyamaha s answer, it seems like you've got some css issue(s). Could you post style.css?

Comment: @Terminus I've added the style in the edit. Thanks for helping me out everyone.

Comment: @Tushar You are right. This is just a way to make things working. I think some bad script is blocking the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below,

You can simply archive this with jQuery `animate` function

Read This [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```js
var click = 0; //keep this flag to identify the click

function menu() {

  var menu = $("nav");

  $(menu).animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  },"slow","easeOutElastic");

  if (click == 0) {
    $(".web_wrapper").animate({"width": "100%"},"slow","easeOutElastic");
    click = 1;
  } else {
    $(".web_wrapper").animate({"width": "80%"},"slow","easeOutElastic");
    click = 0;
  }

  console.log(click);

}
```

```css
nav {
  color: 'black';
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: justify;
  width: 20%;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
}
.web_wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<section class="web_wrapper">
  <header>
    <div style="width: 100%;" id="main">
      <button class="material-icons" id="menu_toggle" onclick="menu();">menu</button>
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
<section class="menu_show">
  <nav style="right:-20%;" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</section>
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it's almost what i'm looking for. The menu now nicely moves in and out on click like it was supposed to(thank you very much for that). But on the same click the webste_wrap has to decrease to 80%.

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt Your welcome...if my answer was helpful..please select is as the answer..also for your question you can do the same toggle for the `web_wrapper`..

Comment: I've marked your comment as the answer. I'm trying to make the toggle for the web_wrapper now. But the toggle keeps changing display:none; instead of just changing the width,

Comment: You're not closing off the nav element. Not sure if that will fix anything though. (It's an error from @robbin 's post) also if you look at his css,he tries to get the menu button to rotate when it has the active class. See this rule in the css `header main button.active {`

Comment: @jlocker What i've done is create another var (var pagina = $('#web_wrap')). And copied your animation from before, now if I look what happens in console is that it switches the display to none, it doesn't change the width propertie itself

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt i have updated my answer..please take a look.

Comment: @jlocker Thank you alot for all your help, the only question I have left, I would like to have the width to go down more smootly (wrapper) It just kinda.. jumps right now.

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt you probably need to have `transition: .3s` on the `section.web_wrapper`'s css. See my answer vanilla JS and css solution ;)

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt i have make it smooth :) Your welcome.

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt check my code above..there i have use jQuery UI to give more smooth easing options..

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <script src"toggle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in top of your codes and check again.

Answer (score 0):

ideally you need to use jQuery but i am also a JS fan.Here you just have to define menu function anywhere but before its called ,ideally in head section,check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/r0d09wcr/1/

```
<head>
<script>
function menu()
{
    alert('dsff');
  var menu = document.querySelector("nav");
  var main = document.querySelector("main");

  if(menu.style.right != '-20%')
  {
      menu.style.right='-20%';
      main.style.width='100%';
  }
  else
  {
      menu.style.right='0%';
      main.style.width='80%';
  }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The error is now indeed gone. Sadly the javascript is still not making the menu appear onlick

Answer (score 0):

First, next time please fiddle your code.

Second, I think this fiddle does what you want:
    `JSFIDDLE:`http://jsfiddle.net/657oudrv/1/

```
$('#menu_toggle').click(function()
{
  var menu = $("nav")
  var main = $("main")

  if(menu.css('right') !== '-20%')
  {
      menu.css('right','-20%')
      main.css('width','100%')
      //Just for test without your css:
      menu.css('margin-left','20%')
  }
  else
  {
      menu.css('right','0%')
      main.css('width','80%')
      //This is also the part of the test
      menu.css('margin-left','0%')
  }
 });
```

Comment: I've added my own css in your fiddle (sorry for the markup using scss with BuildOnSave packages). No I don't any movements anymore. I can't see where I screwed up. But I certainly did somewere. http://jsfiddle.net/657oudrv/3/

Comment: @RobbinvanderJagt Use `position: relative;` on `nav` elment

Comment: @Tushar Added relative to my nav tag. This didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: After loooots of debugging, here is a working copy of the code with a more elegant style: http://jsfiddle.net/657oudrv/6/

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS selector with *.querySelector()*

Try to add id="nav" to your nav HTML element and edit you selector in js accordingly.

in HTML file:

```
<nav id="nav" style="right: -20%;">
```

in toogle.js:

```
var menu = document.querySelector("#nav");
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector for reference

Answer (score 0):

Big wall of code coming up, prepare yourselves. Note that I move the Menu button into the menu section. I also changed the css a lot. Not sure if the text changes color when it's supposed to. The javascript now simply toggles a `menu_show` class on the body and css handles the rest...  I ♥ html5

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo5a50md/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <style type='text/css'>
            * {
                font-size: 12pt;
                padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;
                outline: 0;
                border: 0;
            }

            body {
                width: 100%;
                color: #212121;
            }

            a {
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            li {
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            section {
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .web_wrapper {
                transition: .3s;
                float: left;
                width: 95%;
                height: auto;
            }

            .menu_show .web_wrapper {
                width:80%;
            }

            .menu {
                position: absolute;
                right: 0px;
                width: 5%;
                overflow: hidden;
                height: 100%;
                transition: width .3s;
                background: #607D8B;
            }
            .menu_show .menu {
                overflow: show;
                width: 20%;
            }

            .menu nav {
                position: relative;
                top: 30px;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            .menu_show .menu nav {
                white-space: normal;
                top: 10px;
            }
            .menu_show .menu nav ul {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .menu_show .menu nav ul li {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }

            #menu_toggle {
                text-align: left;
                overflow: hidden;
                position: relative;
                background: transparent;
                transition: 0.3s;
                font-size: 12pt !important;
                transform: rotate(90deg);
                top: 20px;
                right: 10px;
            }
            .menu_show .menu #menu_toggle {
                color: #536DFE;
                top: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        // console logs left in for science
        function ready(fn) {
            console.log('readying');
            if (document.readyState != 'loading'){
                console.log('loading...');
                fn();
            } else {
                console.log('content not loaded');
                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
            }
        }
        ready(function() {
            var body = document.querySelector("body");
            var button = document.getElementById('menu_toggle');
            var menuShowing = false;
            button.addEventListener('click',toggleMenu);

            function toggleMenu()
            {
                if(menuShowing === true)
                {
                    body.classList.remove('menu_show');
                }
                else
                {
                    body.classList.add('menu_show');
                }
                menuShowing = !menuShowing;
            }
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="web_wrapper">
            <main>
                Some content
                <p>more in this paragraph!</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </main>
        </section>
        <section class="menu">
            <button class="material-icons" id="menu_toggle">menu</button>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>1. This is some long stinking text</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                    <li>4</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'll fix any mistakes and try to address any comments. Best way to figure out what something does is to remove the class, rule, w/e from the dev console and see what happens.

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo5a50md/1/)

---

Credit where it's due:

[position: absolute; right: 0px; for animation to work right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214426/5051310) (also height looks good with this set)

the ready function was off StackO... can't find the answer i pulled it from now :(

[wikipedia for the lorem ipsum on the fiddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum)